# How can Serverless be configured to apply the "stack-name" AWS tag to all resources that it deploys, instead of only a subset?

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless, aws-billing, aws-cost-explorer

## Details

### Scenario

I use the [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs) to maintain an HTTP service in a **shared** AWS account (i.e. other apps/services exist on this company account, which are unrelated to mine).

The major AWS resources involved in my service are:

- API Gateway
- Lambda
- CloudWatch
- ElastiCache
- X-Ray

I am trying to determine the **cost** of my Serverless application by using AWS' [Cost Explorer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/).

Given that in order to determine the cost of *my* service I need to filter out other services, I was looking for a way in which Serverless may delineate my deployed resources.

I discovered Serverless automatically applies the `aws:cloudformation:stack-name` [AWS tag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/tag-editor/latest/userguide/tagging.html) based on the `service` property specific in the `serverless.yml` configuration file.

This allowed me, in cost explorer, to apply this value as a **filter** on the `Tag` field.

### Problem

The filtering worked as I expected, **but only for a few of the services**, namely Lambda and CloudWatch. **API Gateway, ElastiCache, and X-Ray seem to be missing the `aws:cloudformation:stack-name` tag entirely**.

### Question

**How can I configure Serverless such that it properly applies the same `aws:cloudformation:stack-name` tag to all my associated resources that it deploys?**

Alternatively, if there is some limitation on this feature or my understanding of AWS tags is incorrect, what are the other routes I may take to achieve my task?

## Serverless Framework Info

### frameworkVersion

#### `3`

### Installed Plugins

*(These may be unrelated to my question, but I list them in case they are somehow relevant.)*

- `serverless-domain-manager`
- `serverless-offline`
- `serverless-vpc-discovery`
- `serverless-plugin-lambda-insights`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `stackTags` property?

> #### 1. Using `provider.stackTags`
>
> All the tags specified under `provider.stackTags` section will be:
>
> - Applied to the stack which contains all the resources that the
>   framework will create for a service
> - Applied to most of the resources
>   created directly or indirectly by the framework. The reason it’s most
>   and not all is detailed in the last section of this article.
>
> ```
> provider:
>   stackTags:
>     stackTag1: value1
>     stackTag2: value2
> ```

Reference: https://mojitocoder.medium.com/aws-resources-tagging-using-serverless-framework-fbfb32122cde